# How to create Google Drive direct download link for .iso to bypass "Download anyway" notification?

Tags: file-upload, download, google-drive-api, vultr

[Download anyway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlGLL.png)

How to create Google Drive direct download link for .iso (or any large) file to bypass "Download anyway" notification and upload it to Vultr.com (and elsewhere)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help you:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=yTib&id=YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_ID

Replace `YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_ID` with yours.

Here's how to get `YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_FILE_ID`:

https://howtogeek.com/747810/how-to-make-a-direct-download-link-for-google-drive-files